# Map two aggregates inside one Model DDD .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I am new to the subject Domain Driven Design and have created an app using .NET Core and Angular 7.

I have this scenario:

I have a Domain layer which has the entities and the aggregates and I have two aggregates: Post, Comment

Each one of them has its own Repository and its own Model and will be saved in the database separately in two tables in the Infrastructure layer.

I have the problem now when I want to show the Post in the frontend. I don't want to send two requests to get the post and then the comments. Rather I want to get both of them in one request which means my aggregates should be connected with each other or I should create new Aggregate and map both models inside.

What is the best practice for that? should I create a new model called, for example, PublicPost and map both objects inside? and is there a way to achieve that dynamically using DI and AutoMapper? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to just be creating an "aggregate" out of every entity. That's not how it's supposed to work. Your aggregate is the domain model. Other related entities are only access and utilized via that aggregate.

In this scenario. Your aggregate is `Post`. `Comment` is *not* an aggregate. It belongs to `Post` and therefore is part of the `Post` aggregate. In other words, on your `Post` model, you should have methods like: `AddComment`, `UpdateComment`, `DeleteComment`, and you'd expose a `Comments` read-only list property to get all the comments.

Even if `Comment` was an aggregate in its own right (i.e. it could stand completely on its own, without being associated with anything else), then you'd be entering the territory of bounded contexts. The `Comment` aggregate would not be same thing as a "comment" in the context of a `Post` (even if they ultimately boil down to the same entity type. You would need one domain where `Post` is the aggregate and `Comment` is managed through that and a completely separate domain where `Comment` is an aggregate on its own, completely unrelated to `Post`.

Comment: But in that case, we will have a performance issue in the database when we have a huge amount of data, let's take the fact of voting for a post that could be 1 million records. Besides, the comments will be managed separately. Which means when a user add a comment, I don't need to get the question out of the database, add the comments to the list and then save it rather targeting the comment table. 

I read about having to aggregate root entities: DomainEntity, SqlEntity and the automapper will do the mapping in between, but we have double entity in this case.

Comment: Hmm, I read your edit now! Just to understand, you comment inside the post are GetOnly and the comments as an Aggregate are to manage that.

Comment: No. Or at least not exactly. They are either separate domains or not. If you need to access comments from a post, that screams that the domains are not separate. Only if a comment was something that can stand on its own (i.e. not related to a post), could it be an aggregate, which frankly doesn't make logical sense. Even so, those would be handled via bounded contexts, one for post and one for comment, and no crossover. The post context, then, would have its own comment, managed completely via the post aggregate.

Comment: Put more simply, perhaps: it's called an aggregate root for a reason. Nothing else in the domain should depend on an aggregate or it's not actually an aggregate. Post depends on comment, so comment by definition cannot be an aggregate, at least in that context.

Comment: I got the idea. One more question, could an Aggregate have more than one repository? or should every table in the aggregate be managed through the aggregate root only?

Comment: The latter. Repo per aggregate.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. If you do end up needing manage the same entity in different bounded contexts, then you'll need a syncronization strategy, such as event sourcing with eventual consistency, etc. Otherwise, you're data will be all messed up.

Comment: I thought about that too. We will have somewhen this strategy. But we are still in startup mode, so we are trying to get things together. But thanks again for the tip.

Comment: @SamySammour _let's take the fact of voting for a post that could be 1 million records. Besides, the comments will be managed separately_ common mistake for people new to DDD. You are bring persistence concerns into your domain, that results in a leaky abstraction.A domain model should **NEVER** be designed with persistence in mind (which is harder than you think). i.e. a Domain Model shouldn't have an `Id` field/property, just for the sake that your RDBMS. Other persistence systems (document DB, xml or json storage) may not require such fields since they dont have foreign-key relation concept

Comment: DDD is used to solve **complex business requirements**,as such you design the model by the business requirements (business process).But this also means that for most trivial cases you don't have (and shouldn't) apply DDD. When you have APIs which are simple CRUDs (ie accessing a blob storage), then you just use CRUD instead of DDD. When you have cases with no business logic, then DDD is not necessary either.What kind of business logic does a (blog)post have? None actually, there is just some input validation and authorization (authorization/authentication is infrastructure concern not domain)

Comment: @Tseng Well, the Post/Comment is only a small part. There is a complexity in the application with the ability to scale the project to Microservices in the future. So, I want to prepare everything now as it requires all other later functions.

I guess I have now a good view of what DDD is all about. I guess the idea of aggregate wasn't clear, but now it is, thanks to you, guys!

Comment: @Tseng for the type of the database, we will have in the future other types like CosmosDb and that is why we have an Entity per database. SqlEntity, CosmosEntity, ...